# Cannot boot Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in emergency mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04 from GRUB but it ends up in Emergency mode and Control-D doesn't load the system.

This is most probably is caused by nvidia drivers:

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 6013d4 ...
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 10ecc0 ...
```

[image]

After adding a boot option `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line, these two messages disappear but the problem still remians -- cannot boot the Ubuntu.
[image]

In addition if I go to recovery mode I cannot enable network there to update drivers, for example.

Comment: Did you look at the output of `journalctl -xb` as suggested in the screenshot? We will need that information.

Comment: `systemctl --failed` is another starting point, to simply name failed unit(s).  Emergency mode should only be triggered by being unable to mount a filesystem (e.g. `var.mount` unit), so I don't expect it is due to nvidia.

Comment: sadly the text of mount errors has never been logged in the journal, due to an oversight which I submitted a patch for today :-(.  So another useful starting point is `mount -a`, to try and get error messages.

Comment: Does the partition mount if you boot from a live-cd  ?  it will determinate if yes or no it is a mount issue or not

Comment: @francoisP which partition :-P ?

Comment: at least / -  /usr & /var   is separated (else /)

Comment: @francoisP / is mounted already.  1) it is logged as "Started remount root..."; 2) other filesystems are mounted ("core", "core", and "chromium"), therefore the root has been mounted already - the root must be mounted before any other filesystem.  Plus, if you know the list of FS which need to be mounted, it is very easy to check from the emergency shell whether they are mounted.  live cd is useful tool but doesn't really help answer this specific point.

Comment: after ths root partition / is mounted : launching a `mount -a`  doesn't give errors or warnings  messages at all ?

Comment: The strange part is we have "Local File Systems (Pre)" still onscreen.  So if a local FS fails, it should be shown sometime after that.  But we don't see any failure onscreen...  (Often, but not necessarily, there is also an annoyingly long timeout while systemd waits for a missing block device to appear).  So it might be necessary to look through all of `journalctl` to find the mystery.

Comment: (helpfully `journalctl` shows errors in red, important "notice"s in bold)

Comment: Thank you for your comments that helped me to find the answer.

Comment: Hey, I am stuck with the same problem today !! Can you please tell me a fix or any way to recover data from this?

Answer (score 3):

As @sourcejedi commented I tried `systemctl --failed` and got the following:

```
 UNIT                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION 
* media-win-Data.mount loaded failed failed /media/win/Data
* media-win-Misc.mount loaded failed failed /media/win/Misc
```

Which are Windows drives (without OS installed on them). After running `mount -a` I got the message that `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda5` cannot be mounted because:

```
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)
```

I turned off `fast startup (recommended)` in Windows 10 according to [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation). After shutting down Windows, Ubuntu boots without complaints.

Interestingly, I was using `fast startup` option for shutting down Windows for more than a month and Ubuntu has not complained about it before. That's why I didn't think that this could be the reason.